# Need help to fill this matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a listo of 1000 numbers $\{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{999}\}$, I need to fill a matrix with these numbers. The matrix must have this form:

$$\left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
x_{9} &x_8 &\cdots& x_0 \\
x_{10} &x_9 &\cdots &x_1 \\
\dots & \cdots& \cdots &\cdots\\
x_{999} &x_{998} & \cdots& x_{990}
\end{array}\right)$$

I have tried with

```
k = 0;
line = {};
mat = {};
Do[
 Do[AppendTo[line, x[[k + i]]], {i, 10}];
 AppendTo[mat, line];
 k = k + 1;, {j, 10}]
```

but it is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Reverse /@ Partition[Range[0, 999], 10, 1]
```

> `{{9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, ... {999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990}}`

Replace `Range[0, 999]` by your `x`.